# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[here_is_json_api](https://api.myjson.com/bins/15baeq)

And my code

```
 ArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                for (int i = 0 ; i<response.length();i++) {

                    try {
                       // JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                       jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonObjectt = jsonObject.getJSONObject("search_result");
                        Users users = new Users();
                        users.setId(jsonObjectt.getString("id"));
                        users.setUser(jsonObjectt.getString("User"));
                        users.setName(jsonObjectt.getString("name"));
                        users.setWho(jsonObjectt.getString("who"));
                        users.setImage(jsonObjectt.getString("image"));
                        userlist.add(users);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                setRvadapter(userlist);
```

i can not fetch any data from api , Its says JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: it should be fairly obvious that you make a request for an array with JsonArrayRequest but the data returned is not an array but an object.

Comment: I saw many question in here like this but I can not solved with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using JsonArray as a response and your web service return a jsonobject

```
new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                        JSONArray teachers = response.getJSONArray("search_result");
                        for(int i = 0; i < teachers.length() ; i++) {
                            // do what ever you want with
                            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
                            // here is how to get name
                            teacher.setId(teachers.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                            // do the rest like this.
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you ,I do that but not showing error or data , can you see my code please 

 [Code Link](https://pastebin.com/J9ppRNzi).

Comment: because you are using try catch so you need to debug line by line and you will know on which line it crashs. Maybe wrong value maybe there is no value

Comment: you are right , its says "No value for search_result" but api is not null

Comment: can you please log the content of response?

Comment: [log is here ](https://pastebin.com/M62WFahN)  ' JSONArray teachers = response.getJSONArray("search_result");' here is error means no value , I request you to see the api , 'search_result' is child value

Comment: i want to have some break points before this line i would like to see the content of response object.